# Measuring distance traveled, in 3D using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, arcgis-pro, 3d, measurements

I'm working in ArcGIS pro, I have tracking data from a bird's flight path and want to know how far the bird flew. I started with Google Earth KML Layer and imported to ArcGIS Pro. This layer has data for each point along the bird's flight path at regular intervals. In the attribute table, each point has an X, Y location and altitude height.

We want to measure the total distance the bird flew. The bird flew up and down, in circles, loops, etc. So we are not just measuring in 2 dimensions, but the altitude is a factor as well.

We looked at the [Generate Near Table tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm) but this does not account for altitude. 
We can measure distances in [3D using the measure tool in ArcGlobe](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/about-measuring-distances-and-heights-in-3d-globe.htm). However, we have over 6000 points. 
Lastly, we looked at the [near 3D tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/near-3d.htm), but this seems to measure between feature classes, instead of items within the same feature class.

Can anyone recommend another tool or workflow for us to use?